# Searching an item and a location in the same input field

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm facing a problem. I search a solution on the internet but didn't find any solution.

Here is my problem :
I have some items stored in a DB table with a location (lat and long). For example a aircraft in Paris, a bike in new york, another bike in paris, a dishwasher in Tokyo etc...
I would like to find all the item of a type near a place.

For that, I did 2 input fields : One called "What" and another called "Where" (this one has autocompletion of google maps). If you entered "Bike" in the first field and "Paris" in the second, it works perfectly ! (I use geocode to get the coordinates of the "Where" field" and then use a SQL query to filter the object type)

But my goal is to achieve this in one input field ! A global field where the user can enter "Bike Paris" or "Paris Bike" and get the result of all bike near paris that are in the DB. As it is the case in google maps : if you type "mobile phone chicago": it will interpret "mobile phone near chicago" and get your results. The difficulty is to interpret which word i a place and which one is not.

Do you have a idea of how to achieve this ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This need some work. One way to do it is to use some means of certain machine learning classification algorithms. What they basically does is that they are trained using certain kind of dataset containing observations to classify objects into certain classes. So when they are given a new object they can classify it accordingly.

You can read more about them [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mining)

If you can't manage that sort of complexity one simple thing you could do is search both the words the user enters in the smallest dataset(ie, things or place) if one of them is very large than the other, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This **SQL** statement

```
SELECT *  FROM `mixedsearch` WHERE `place` IN ('London','Bike') AND `type` IN ('London','Bike')
```

selects

```
London | Bike
```

From this table

```
place | type
Paris | Bike
Paris | Plane
Paris | Car
London | Bike
London | Car
London | Plane
Tokyo | Dishwasher
Tokyo | Bike
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f708e/3)

How you translate your input field to the SELECT statement dependson your application

Comment: Hello David, the problem is that my table is not place+type but more like lat+lng+type. Like : "Bike 148.145 120.34". When the user enter "Eiffel Tower Paris Bike", I need to geocode just "Eiffel Tower paris". So I need to interpret what is a place and what is an item ...

Comment: Are you using Ajax,PHp & MySQL? You want to get info from 1 input,Get lat/lng of address and search for matches for other items on input?

Comment: Exactly, I'm using Ajax, Php and MySQL. I want to interpret what in the input field needs to be geocode (to produce a lat and long" and what is just an item.

Comment: Is your locations limited or can the user type in any city.

Comment: The user can type anything in the input field :)

Comment: I think you will need to go down the route Emil suggested unless you can limit input to place & type